# Angular Material Slider 24h formatting with minutes steps

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I would slide with minutes steps

I'm using [Angular Material Slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview)

Actually I can slide every minutes.

```
formatLabel(value: number | null) {
  if (!value) {
    return '00:00';
  }
  if(value===0) {
    return '00:00'
  }
  if(value===24) {
    return '23:59'
  }

  let decimalPart = +value.toString().replace(/^[^\.]+/,'0');
  let mm = decimalPart * 60;
  mm=Math.round(mm)
  var mmPart = mm.toString().length == 1 ?  "0"+mm.toString() : mm.toString();
  if(mmPart =='60') {
    mmPart='00'
  }

  if (value >= 0) {
    let valueStr = value.toFixed(2);
    let strArr = valueStr.split(".");
    if(strArr[0].length == 1) {
      strArr[0] = "0" + strArr[0];
    }
    var hhPart = strArr[0];
    //console.log(strArr);
  }

  return hhPart + ":" + mmPart;
}
```

My actual problem is when I arrive to 24 on screen I get 24:00.

I would that it stops on 23:59 so I added a condition :

```
if(value===24) {
  return '23:59'
}
```

But now I get two values of 23:59 on  24:00 -1 minutes and on 24:00 I would find a solution to stop slider on 23:59

[Here's a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-24h-slider?file=app/slider-formatting-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your max value to :

```
24 - 1/60  //that is 1 minute less of 24 hours
i.e.
<mat-slider max=23.9834>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the max in your template will do the work

```
 <mat-slider ... max="23.99">
```

That way you will never reach 24 therefore you can remove the check you were previously doing.